# For all possible combinations of rows and columns, aggregate values of pandas dataframe on the basis of their relative distance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, combinations, aggregation

I have a Dataframe of NxM values, and i need to iterate through it in order to identify all possible combinantions of lenght 1, 2, 3... up to NxM-1 of rows and columns.
For each of these combinations, I want to aggregate values. Let's make an example: df_unreduced is my initial dataframe

```
df_unreduced= pd.DataFrame({"Strike":[50,75,100,125,150],
                              "31/12/2021":[1,2,3,4,5],
                              "31/12/2022":[6,7,8,9,10],
                              "31/12/2023":[11,12,13,14,15],
                              "31/12/2024":[16,17,18,19,20],
                              "31/12/2025":[21,22,23,24,25]})
```

Here I focus on just one possible combination of rows and columns. lets say I want to aggregate on these 4 "nodes" (being node=intersection between one row and one column) of my initial df:

```
row=75 , col= "31/12/2022"
row=75 , col= "31/12/2024"
row=150 , col= "31/12/2022"
row=150 , col= "31/12/2024"
```

the expected result is:

```
df_reduce=pd.DataFrame({"Strike":[75,150],
                              "31/12/2022":[45.8333,135.8333],
                              "31/12/2024":[41.6667, 101.6667]})
```

if the combination was:

```
row=75 , col= "31/12/2022"
row=75 , col= "31/12/2024"
row=125 , col= "31/12/2022"
row=125 , col= "31/12/2024"
```

the expected result would be:

```
df_reduced = pd.DataFrame({"Strike": [75, 125],
                               "31/12/2022": [36.25, 111.25],
                               "31/12/2024": [51.25, 126.25]})
```

and so on. the key point here is that, as you may see from the expected results, i must linearly weight values that fall between two nodes, before summing them. To achieve the expected result i initially summed by rows and then by columns, but if i did the other way around, the results would be unchanged.
once defined the right summing code, I have to loop between all possible combinations.
Whatever the number/position of nodes i aggregate on, the sum of values within the reduced data frame must match the sum of values within the unreduced one.

EDIT: in order to elaborate a bit more on the aggregation and the expected result: in my df_unreduced the "Strike" array is [50, 75, 100, 125, 150]. As said i'm keen to adopt a two steps approach, summing up by rows and then by columns.
Let's take my first example: the first node i need to aggregate on (call it A) is (75, "31/12/2022") and the third (D) is (150, "31/12/2022"). in the row dimension, between A and D I have two nodes B=(100, "31/12/2022") and C=(125,"31/12/2022"). the distance between 75 and 150 is 75: 100 falls 1/3 away from A and 2/3 away from D, while 125 is 1/3 away from D and 2/3 away from A. for this reason, when aggregating on A, I can say the that A_AGG_row = A + (1-1/3)*B + (1-2/3)*C. Conversely, D_AGG_row = D + (1-1/3)*C + (1-2/3)* B.

on the column dimension, if we consider F=(75, "31/12/2024"), we have that E=(75, "31/12/2023") is halfway between A and F so A_AGG_col = A_AGG_row + (1-1/2)*E_AGG_row and F_AGG_col = F_AGG_row + (1-1/2)*E_AGG_row (where E_AGG_row is the result of the previous summing by rows on node E).

In more scientifc terms, when summing up rows I need to split linearly the value of the generic node "i" falling between two selected nodes, A and D, by applying this formulas:

1. 1-(Strike_i -Strike_A)/(Strike_D - Strike_A) -> on node A
2. 1-(Strike_D -Strike_i)/(Strike_D - Strike_A) -> on node D

when summing up columns I need to split linearly the value of the generic node "j" falling between two selected nodes, A and F

3. 1-(Date_j-Date_A)/(Date_F - Date_A)  -> on node A
4. 1-(Date_F-Date_j)/(Date_F - Date_A) -> on node D

these are the complete steps:
1.df_unreduced

|  | 31/12/2021 | 31/12/2022 | 31/12/2023 | 31/12/2024 | 31/12/2025 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 1 | 6 | 11 | 16 | 21 |
| 75 | 2 | 7 | 12 | 17 | 22 |
| 100 | 3 | 8 | 13 | 18 | 23 |
| 125 | 4 | 9 | 14 | 19 | 24 |
| 150 | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 | 25 |

2. summing rows:

|  | 31/12/2021 | 31/12/2022 | 31/12/2023 | 31/12/2024 | 31/12/2025 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 75 | 6.333 | 21.333 | 36.333 | 51.333 | 63.333 |
| 100 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 125 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 150 | 8.667 | 18.667 | 28.667 | 38.667 | 48.667 |

3. summing by cols:

|  | 31/12/2021 | 31/12/2022 | 31/12/2023 | 31/12/2024 | 31/12/2025 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 75 |  | 45.833 |  | 135.833 |  |
| 100 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 125 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 150 |  | 41.667 |  | 101.667 |  |

I hope this clarifies the problem

thanks

Comment: Could you please could you further elaborate the steps?. How are you getting decimals?

Comment: I Rafael, i tried to explain this better by editing my initial post. thank you for your interest